# AWS Lambda Layers: does it have a cold start separated from the main lambda?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I mean, when the main lambda starts, does it awaits the layers start before? What is happening is that my main lambda is presenting errors at the first start(when its cold) while including contents from the layers. At the second execution, everything works fine and the content from the layer is included as expected. Are my suspicious right? Is this behavior something expected? Just to you guys have in mind: the content from these layers aren't heavy, have simple variables with some keys and salts used to encryption functions.

Edit 1:

content from layer: chat_privatekey_salt.php

```
<?php
$salt='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx+xxx=';
?>
```

content from main lambda: dowork.php

```
<?php
require_once('pusher_7.0.2/autoload.php'); //this comes from the current lambda
function fake_trigger($channels,$event,$data){
    require_once('/bref/lib/php/pem_files/chat_privatekey_salt.php'); //comes from layer, error is here
    foreach($channels as $value){
        //do some work using variable $salt 
    }
}
?>
```

The error is: `Notice: Undefined variable: salt in /var/task/assets/libs/dowork.php on line 6`

Comment: A layer does not start, therefore no, it does not have / cannot have a separate start. You need to provide a lot more details to enable us to help you, e.g. what error, what is in the layers, what the code is, etc. If you do `something = getSomethingFromLayer(); setSomething(); assertSomethingWasSet(something);` this might fail on the first invocation but work in subsequent ones, nobody knows.

Comment: @luk2302 just updated the question with the code.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @luk2302 Notice: Undefined variable: salt in /var/task/assets/libs/dowork.php on line 6

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't refer to a variable named `salt`. Are you sure the two earlier required PHP files loaded and had the correct code?

Comment: @jarmod it's inside the foreach. I added it as a comment, but the real code is 
```$options = array('cluster' => 'us2','useTLS' => true,'encrypted' => true,'encryption_master_key_base64'=>base64_encode(openssl_digest($salt.$value,'SHA256', true)));```

Comment: @jarmod at the second execution it starts to work properly.

Comment: In Lambda you typically use relative references to files, not absolute references. Are you 100% sure the file is at `/bref/lib/php/pem_files/chat_privatekey_salt.php` (test for its existence) and that it has exactly the contents you expect and the PHP script in it actually defines the variable `salt` unconditionally?

Comment: @jarmod Before I noticed the problem, I was including only "pem_files/chat_privatekey_salt.php", I changed it by the absolute path for tests purposes. I also tried to make a var_dump($salt) and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem wasn't the lambda layer or the path neither. Actually the problem was the require_once(). After adding some lines of code to log the value of $salt, I noticed that it works properly at the first time of calling function fake_trigger, but the at the next calls it fails due to the behavior of require_once which works as its name explicitly say(lol). So changing it by include() have made de trick.

Comment: This appears to be exactly the opposite of what you reported earlier which was "at the second execution it starts to work properly."

Comment: @jarmod yes... exactly the opposite! But the fake_trigger function was being called only at the first execution. This system is in regard of  messages read confirmation. Since after the first execution the algorithm marks the messages as read, at the second execution, fake_trigger() wasn't being called anymore, so the problem was being hidden. By setting the messages as unread again, I could see the problem was keeping at any execution, not only on the first one. But now it's fixed, thank you for everyone whom helped.